# ASP sqlDataSource racle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm using an sqlDataSource for a grid control. But i'm having issues when executing the insert command. I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.Client as the provider.

This is the code sqlDataSource generated

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO &quot;EE_AP_KPIS&quot; (&quot;ID&quot;, &quot;TITLE&quot;, &quot;SECTION_ID&quot;, &quot;DISPLAY_TITLE&quot;, &quot;SORT&quot;) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM &quot;EE_AP_KPIS&quot;">
                                   <InsertParameters>
                                       <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Decimal" />
                                       <asp:Parameter Name="TITLE" Type="String" />
                                       <asp:Parameter Name="SECTION_ID" Type="Decimal" />
                                       <asp:Parameter Name="DISPLAY_TITLE" Type="String" />
                                       <asp:Parameter Name="SORT" Type="Decimal" />
                                   </InsertParameters>                                       
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get the following error `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character`

I realise it could be a value in my data but I want to confirm if the code above looks OK? I'm not sure if the sqlDataSource has generated the sql correctly. Is `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` the correct way to bind variables? If not, any idea why it generated it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The `?` character is how you represent a bind parameter in Java using JDBC.  .NET tends to indicate parameters as `:paramname` instead.

So, try replacing

```
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

with

```
VALUES (:ID, :TITLE, :SECTION_ID, :DISPLAY_TITLE, :SORT)
```

Comment: That is what I thought but why would VS automatically use ? when I define the sqlDataSource provider as Oracle.DataAccess?